# Can the ethereum attach message like bitcoin in transaction?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction

Can the ethereum attach a message in transaction? for example, l want attach the message "hello" in common transaction(not contract create). thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every transaction has a `data` field. In the case of calls to smart contracts, the `data` field is used to specify what function is being called and with what parameters.

For a simple transfer of ether to a non-contract (an "externally owned account"), the `data` field is unused, so you can put whatever data you want in there.